# How to change a CSS file inside a .war file deployed in a remote Jboss

Tags: jboss5.x, war, centos5

So I have a remote server where i upload via FTP an .war file to the deploy folder. So there are times when i just need to change one line or two from an css file. Unitl now i have to redeply the whole war (a whole hour just to upload the file). So i was wondering what could i do if I need to modify just one file?

The remote server is a Centos 5.5 with Jboss 5.1. I can access the remote server via SSH but i dont have too many permission.

Here some random code, dont worry about this :)

```
    function basedir(){
    var basedir = document.location.href;
    basedir = basedir.substring(0, basedir.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/';
    return basedir;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are software deployment tools that can help you achieving just that. For instance, [KwateeSDCM](http://www.kwatee.net) will actually only upload modified files (based on an MD5 hash) between the currently installed war and your updated one.

Comment: Thanks Jhonthats an interesting answer!